# React: Module not found: Can't resolve 'xmlhttprequest'

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, xmlhttprequest, truffle

I'm getting an error when trying to build my React project:

> ./node_modules/ethers/utils/web.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'xmlhttprequest' in '/mnt/c/Users/.../node_modules/ethers/utils'

In package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.2"
  },
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hmmm exact same issue! using the latest `truffle-contact@4.0.1`

Comment: After some searching it seems related to webpack not packaging xmlhttprequest properly. The suggestion is to do something specific to package xmlhttprequest in a custom webpack config. My issue is that I don't have a custom webpack config because truffle takes care of that for me. There are instructions on how to set it up: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/bundling-with-webpack but it's more advanced than I'd like to get for this simple project.

Comment: Yeah something seems broken with the latest `truffle-contract` (when used within the browser). I filled [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1614).

Comment: Getting a similar error when using browserify to bundle a project. I'm using truffle-contract as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got my project working again by not importing 'truffle-contract'.
There's a React Truffle example here: https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box
which doesn't import truffle-contract.
I made my project more like that one.
I then had to change my code to use the contract interface provided by web3: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this problem you need to install a different version of ethers as explained in this issue:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1614#issuecomment-452158490

Exact comment with solution:

> ethers (v4.0.0-beta.1) gets installed as a dependency of web3-eth-abi
>   (v1.0.0-beta.37) Which leads to the xmlhttprequest complaint and
>   basically makes truffle-contract unusable. I was able to get around it
>   for now by manually upping ethers to v4.0.20.
>
> $ npm install ethers@4.0.20